# How do I get Mocha "it" messages and errors as strings?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, bdd, console.log

I am using Mocha for in-browser testing. By default, it generates a report directly in the web page (in a div with the ID "mocha" - one message for each "it" block).

I want to get the message of each "it" and the exception thrown (if any) when they are triggered, so I can build a custom report.

For the following code:

```
it("Should throw an error", () => {
  assert(false, 'This is an error message')
})
```

It will create `<li class="test fail">` containing the text:

```
Should throw an error
AssertionError: This is an error message (...)
```

Is there a way to capture the output of these messages as strings?

Comment: Capture them in what context? External to the test or within the test?

Comment: Within the test. Just as soon as the message appears on the page, get the message as a string in a script in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this by doing an `.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', event => ...)` to the mocha div and getting the innerText of the elements I wanted. This will trigger every time a new element appears anywhere in the mocha div. The element can be retrieved with `event.target`.